# Application stuck's when granting read access to several threads from the same file

Tags: c++, database-design, operating-system

We developed a server application in delphi 2010.

In this case the server runs multiple threads that access the same file (sized aprox 2.5GB) for reading data in a siquential access, on job #1 (a big & long calculating job).

The file is stored on a win2012 machine on a 240GB SSD drive.
While this job (#1) is running NO WRITE jobs are done to the same file.

The problem at hand is that when job #1 is running, the same server (exe) that
runs diffrent threads on different jobs, CAN'T access/read different files via different threads (jobs), on a different directories on the same drive... also
at the same time we can see that the CPU is LOW - approx 16%.

- Where should we start looking?
- Is this some kind of windows file access limitation?
- Is this a driver limitation?

**More Info:**
We use the command

```
CreateFileW(FileName, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ OR FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NIL, 
        OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL OR FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS, 0);
```

**Additional Hardware Info:**

- Mother Board - Gigabyte x99-Gaming5 (intel Chipset)
- CPU - Intel Core i7-5930K
- Memory - 32GB 2133Mhz
- OS - Windows 2012R2
- HD - Corsair XT 240GB SSD

Comment: Is the problem "low performance" as stated in the heading or "can't access" as stated in the text?

Comment: I'm sorry - you are right.... the heading is wrong and i'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the server is executed on a single process, and this single process is creating all the jobs that create multiple threads. So, all threads are counted as threads of the same process.

The threads have a memory footprint and the number of threads that are allowed to be created in the same process is dependant of this footprint, as the process has also limited available memory it can use. **The bigger the memory footprint of a thread the smaller the amount of threads that can be created in the same process.**

If you haven't done this already, as a first step of investigation, please have a look on:

1. the number of threads your server application is creating and handling simultaneously (as a whole for all the jobs)
2. reconsider the size of the stack every thread is maintaining and using.